# Replace Observations present in one column to another column

Tags: r

I have a DF that contains columns and observations as shown below below.

```
WaterSource <- c("Rain", "Piped Water", "Well", "Other (please specifiy)" , "Rain", "Other (please specifiy)")
OtherMainSource <- c(NA, NA,NA,"River", NA, "Water vendor")
DF <- data.frame(WaterSource, OtherMainSource)

> DF
              WaterSource OtherMainSource
1                    Rain            <NA>
2             Piped Water            <NA>
3                    Well            <NA>
4 Other (please specifiy)           River
5                    Rain            <NA>
6 Other (please specifiy)    Water vendor
```

I'd like to move all observations that are in 2nd column `OtherMainSource`, to NA's spaces present in the first columns called `WaterSource`

I'd like the final DF to be like this:

```
   WaterSource OtherMainSource
1         Rain            <NA>
2  Piped Water            <NA>
3         Well            <NA>
4        River           River
5         Rain            <NA>
6 Water vendor    Water vendor
```

How do I go about replacing these observations?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you want to replace the values in `WaterSource` when there is a non `NA` value in `OtherMainSource`. Here is a base R method:

```r
DF$WaterSource[
    !is.na(OtherMainSource)
]  <- DF$OtherMainSource[
    !is.na(OtherMainSource)
]

DF

#    WaterSource OtherMainSource
# 1         Rain            <NA>
# 2  Piped Water            <NA>
# 3         Well            <NA>
# 4        River           River
# 5         Rain            <NA>
# 6 Water vendor    Water vendor
```

Alternatively you could use the [`mutate()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) function from [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/):

```r
library(dplyr)
DF  |>
    mutate(
        WaterSource = ifelse(
            is.na(OtherMainSource),
            WaterSource,
            OtherMainSource
        )
    )
# same output as above
```

Or you could use the [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) package.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[!is.na(OtherMainSource), WaterSource := OtherMainSource]
```

The `data.table` approach is likely to be the fastest as you are modifying in place, and only modifying the values that need to be changed (rather than creating a new vector the length of the column as in the `dplyr` approach). But much of the time the speed difference will be negligible, and the most important thing will be to write code that is easy to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

A simple base R ifelse statement will do. I made a new column `WaterSource_2` to verify, but could overwrite `WaterSource` if desired (not advised)

```
DF$WaterSource_2 <- ifelse(!is.na(DF$OtherMainSource), 
                           DF$OtherMainSource, DF$WaterSource)
```

You could also overwrite by indexing whenever "Other" is denoted:

```
idx <- grep("Other", DF$WaterSource)
DF[idx, "WaterSource"] <- DF[idx, "OtherMainSource"]
```